# If possible, how can one stop a print to stdout from interrupting what's been typed?

Tags: python, terminal, chat, stdout, interruption

I have a basic command-line chat client and server in Python, but this would be applicable to probably any language. I ran into a very obvious problem, and I'm not sure if there would be any way around it (aside from using a GUI! Which would quickly solve the problem). When the server sends a message to the client, causing the client to `print()` the message, it's inserted in the exact same place where the person would be typing their own message, causing it to be split by the incoming message. For example (written as # comments to avoid weird syntax highlighting):

```
# Client1: Knock-knock!
# Client2: Who's there?
# Client1: Interrupting cow!
# Client2: Inter
# Client1: MOOOOOOO
# Client2: rupting cow who?
```

Where Client2 hasn't hit enter since typing `Who's there?`.

So obviously, there's all sorts of workarounds like panels on a GUI, but I'm curious to know if there's anyway to implement this strictly in the native terminal/command prompt. I couldn't find anything remotely like this during my searching the internet for a solution! Thanks!

Comment: (chanting) GUI! GUI! GUI! Seriously though, what exactly do you want to happen? Do you want Client1's message to be printed *only after* Client2 hits return? Or do you want Client1's message to be prefixed with a `\n` so that it leaves spaces for Client2 to finish typing? (But in that case, what if Client2 types multiple lines?)

Comment: GUI GUI. I'm more interested to see if it's possible! It's a chat client, it has to be live-updating, it's incredibly hard to hold a conversation when you have to type a message to see the response to a message typed prior! So I would want it to print Client1's message, and move what Client2 was typing underneath the newly received message so they can keep typing like nothing ever happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use something like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/ which lets you set up a terminal with a cursor.

You can move the cursor "up" when you want to print output from the other connection and then move it back down when you want to get input.

If you want to get *crazy* you can do all that magic by yourself with terminal control commands (on windows you'll need colorama) which will let you do things like:

```
print("\033[6;3HHello")
```

Which moves the cursor to x,y. This requires an ansi terminal.

Comment: Wow! That's really neat stuff, tons of possibilities there! Thanks for that.